# camera is not working in python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, camera

This is code :

```
import cv2

cv2.namedWindow("preview")
 vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if vc.isOpened(): # try to get the first frame
rval, frame = vc.read()
else:
rval = False

 while rval:
cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
rval, frame = vc.read()
key = cv2.waitKey(20)
if key == 27: # exit on ESC
    break
cv2.destroyWindow("preview")
```

but  camera preview is totally black

it may be the driver problem please is it the driver problem and how can i solve it

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code.

Comment: if it it driver problem then it is not place for your problem - you will have to search on different portals.

Comment: I said may be!!

Comment: If you downloaded opencv through pip, it shouldn't have proper video support on osx/linux. See also the [FAQ on PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python). If you want video / webcam support, you will probably have to build opencv from source.

Comment: I have used pycharm for that

Comment: You can change it to a video to see if it's good to use.And I found that your code was not formatted correctly, there was a space in front of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to just need to install the camera drivers that supports your device else the code is fine kindly reinstall the driver or install another driver may be from the official site of PC maker website